# how to jump to the secure&privacy setting by swift5 in mac

Tags: macos, swift5

I want to use a `NSAlert` button, then jump to Security & Privacy setting in Mac by Swift 5, what should I do?

```
alert.addButton(withTitle: "yes") 
alert.addButton(withTitle: "no")

if let window = view.window {
    
    alert.beginSheetModal(for: window) { [unowned self] (response) in 
     
        switch response.rawValue {
        case 1000: //how to  jump to system setting?
               break
        case 1001: break
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Preference Pane with `NSWorkspace`

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane"))
```